# Where do you view SSIS package after import and migrate to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

After installing SQL Server 2005 Backward Compatibility Components and SQL Server 2000 DTS Designer Components in my SQL Server 2008 R2 Server, I successfully migrated a SQL Server 2000 DTS Package.  I then successfully migrated it to SSIS within my SQL Server 2008 R2 Server.  The million dollar question is - where do I view or edit the SSIS project? I say the steps were successful because both processes returned successful message.

Thanks for any tips provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is the same as in SQL server 2005 as far as I can recall.

Enter the SQL Server 2008 setup and go through the initial screens. On the Feature Selection screen, make sure you have  SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio selected (under Shared Features). Use the BI studio to edit SSIS projects as you would in 2005.

If you have an existing package on the server that you want to edit, connect to Integration services of the server in question from your SSMS, export the package to your PC, edit it in BI, then import it back to the server overwriting the older version (better rename the old version just to be safe).